# how to create TPM_AUTHDATA as input in tpm commands ?

Tags: windows, hmac, trusted-computing, tpm

I'm writing my first program which use tpm (version 1.2) services in Windows 7 using TBS, in this program I'm trying to execute the TPM_CreateWrapKey command.
I noticed that many commands like the TPM_CreateWrapKey require as last parameter **TPM_AUTHDATA** which is basically the output of HMAC on 4 parameters - sha1 digset on some of the input parameters which marked as 1s,2s,3s.. and 3 other input parameters which marked as 2H1,3H1 and 4H1.
What I don't understand is the key for the HMAC , according to the documentation the key described as : **parentKey.usageAuth** .
In my case the parent key is the SRK since I don't have any other key (beside the EK).
Is the useAuth of the SRK was created during the take ownership proccess? if it does how can I get it? and if not how should I generate it?

tpm spec: http://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/resources/tpm_main_specification

tpm commands (the TPM_CreateWrapKey command appears in chapter 10.4) : http://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/resources/tpm_main_specification